# iPhone SE 2020 (iOS 16.1) NFC reader not working

Tags: iphone, hardware, nfc

My phone is about 2.5 years old, and in that time the NFC reader has worked without problems. But recently my phone stopped being able to read NFC chips - such as wireless payment.

I've tried to remove the cover, which doesn't work. I've also done a forced restart, updated to the newest iOS (16.1) and done a factory reset, without luck. This makes me think that it is a hardware issue, even though I've never had the phone opened up, so I can't see how hardware could've been damaged.

I've then tried to see if the NFC flex cable wasn't connected properly to the motherboard, and I made sure the screws connecting the flex cable to the motherboard were properly tightened - as most google searches recommended checking this. As you probably guessed, this also didn't work.

Also, as far as I can understand, the QI wireless charging is built into the NFC antenna. But the wireless charging works fine (using a QI charger). Would this indicate that the problem is not with the NFC antenna? Is it possible that there is a loose connection elsewhere than the flex cable?

What else can I do? Is it possible to replace the NFC antenna myself? Or is the problem elsewere?

Edit: Added extra info